# How to group/nest routes in rails like you can in laravel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-routes

I'm switching from using a laravel php framework to a rails framework and cannot figure out how to get nested routes working in rails like it did in laravel. In laravel it would work like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'healthandwelness'], function() {

  Route::get('', [
    'uses' => 'healthandwelness@index'
  ]);

  Route::group(['prefix' => 'healthcare'], function() {

    Route::get('', [
      'uses' => 'healthcare@index'
    ]);

    Route::get('{article_id}', [
      'uses' => 'article@index'
    ]);  

  ]);

});
```

Which would give me the routes:

```
/healthandwellness
/healthandwellness/healthcare
/healthandwellness/healthcare/{article_id}
```

The only way I've seen to nest routes in rails is with resources which I've used to tried and recreate my routes in rails like this:

```
resources :healthandwellness do
  resources :healthcare 
end
```

But the nature of resources makes this route into the following gets:

```
/healthandwellness
/healthandwellness/:health_and_wellness_id/healthcare
/healthandwellness/:health_and_wellness_id/healthcare/:id
```

Is there anyway to do what I am looking for in rails and recreate what I was able to do laravel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `namespace`:

```
namespace :healthandwellness do
  resources :healthcare
end
```

Note that this assumes that your controller is located in `app/controllers/healthsandwellness/healthcare_controller.rb` and should be defined as follows:

```
class Healthandwellness::HealthcareController < ApplicationController
  ...
end
```

If you want to keep your controller under `apps/controller` and not scoped under `app/controllers/healthandwellness`, you can use `scope`:

```
scope '/healthandwellness' do
  resources :healthcare
end
```

The documentation [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) provides good examples of `namespace` and `scope`